# Return an array from VB Script to JQuery in classic ASP for Autocomplete text box

Tags: jquery, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am a beginner for web development and currently adding an autocomplete text box which retrieved data from MS SQL server based on user input.

I declared an array called CodeList in JQuery and casting the return code from VB script function called getListOfCode. It is throwing an error that array: CodeList cannot be casted into function: getListOfCode.
(Error code: ASP_0106_:_80020005|Type_Mismatch)

I tried to Redim Function getListOfCode() as an array in VB script but it did not work. Could anyone please provide me some advice?

VB Script part

```
<%
Function getListOfCode()


    Set objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL = "Select distinct Code_A, Code_A + " & " ' : ' " & _
                " + Long_Name AS Code_Name " & _
                 "FROM  CodeMaster " & _
                 "Where Type = 'A' "

    objrec.Open  strSQL, objConnect

    Dim CodeList(), i
    Redim CodeList(objrec.Fields.Count - 1)
    i = 0

    Do Until i < objrec.Fields.Count - 1

        CodeList(i) = objrec.Fields("Code_Name")

        i = i + 1
        objrec.MoveNext

    Loop

    getListOfCode = CodeList
    >> To return an array to Java Script with casting. 
    If I write CodeList(i), it does not throw an error 
    which means getListOfCode is being recognized as a string

    objRec.Close
    Set objRec = Nothing

End Function 
%>
```

JQuery part

```
  $(function() {
var CodeList = [
  <%= getListOfCode() %>
];
$( "#frmCode" ).autocomplete({
  source: CodeList
}); 
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes with your suggestion and changed to use a global variable instead of casting to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

`getListOfCode = CodeList`

to:

```
getListOfCode = String.Join(",", CodeList)
```

And that should do it!  The string will be rendered as a raw JSON array in the ASP file.

Also, change this line:

```
CodeList(i) = objrec.Fields("Code_Name")
```

to include quotes such that the JS interprets your strings as actual JS strings:

```
CodeList(i) = """" & objrec.Fields("Code_Name") & """"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I just tried and it is still not working..

The below error occurred:

800a01c2|Wrong_number_of_arguments_or_invalid_property_assignment:_'String'

Also, do I not have to re-define getListOfCode as it is recognized as a string, not a array.

Comment: See my update...the output JS variables aren't wrapped in quotes.

Comment: I made changes with your suggestion and changed to use a global variable instead of casting to the function. It really helped! Thank you.